# Serial port stops receiving data after certain amount of time on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, windows-10

Since couple of months I am a developer of quite big vehicle weight measurement system. System is designed as distributed software (based on .NET) and has many components which communicate using RabbitMQ. This information is just for an general overview.

Our real devices communicates with System Local Services using TCP Sockets and Serial Ports available in Windows. We did not have any communication issues so far, but recently we installed our software on industrial terminal with Windows 10 Professional installed on it.

I face big issues with scale communication using Serial Port. Scale is designed to send data frame containing the value, over and over again, indefinitely, through Serial Port (RS232). My program receives the data and everything is working as expected (one way communication, I do not send anything to scale). The problem is, after approx. 1 hour, data stops to be received by program - no value updates appear. If I close and reopen an application, everything gets working again and after ~1 hour same happens.

Once, when communication was stuck, I've unplugged the RS232 cable and plugged in again after 1-2 minutes - application started receiving data again - no restart was required. I've even ended up with some dirty hack like following:

if same frame is being received by program for n minutes, close and reopen port connection - unfortunately still no luck (I know this is bad approach anyway). All power saving settings were disabled in Windows. The program runs on other machines without a hassle. Problem occurs on this one particular industrial terminal (with touch screen) only. Have you maybe faced similar issues? I am missing further ideas and I am getting frustrated...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how is the app run, rdp session, logged in directly, scheduled task, service?

Comment: hi @BugFinder, thanks for reply. App is running as a standard Windows application (app is written in WPF), user is logged in directly to Windows (desktop is accessible under the app). Do you need some more information?

Comment: Are there any GPOs about idle times?

Comment: Execuse me, but what are GPOs? Could you give me some research direction? I'll get familiar with this and let you know about results. Thanks...

Comment: GPO is Group Policy ..

Comment: Are you thinking about  "Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit"? If so, I need to add that no screen saver appears and system does not get locked. This value is set to 'Not Defined'.

Comment: Are you using a real serial RS232 cable or a USB to Serial converter? (I know you say RS232 but just want to verify)

Comment: Yes, it was real RS232 (motherboard slot) - after switching to USB to Serial converter issue dissapeared. Before that I've performed complex tests including buffer overflow etc. It seemed to be hardware issue - program behaves correctly on other machine. USB to Serial Converter was the solution - unfortunately.